# Difference in SQL Date Query with Parenthesis

Tags: sql, mysql-python

I inherited an a multiple Machine Learning processes that use essentially the same date query except for parenthesis. The following 3 date queries give a different number of rows. What exactly is the difference between each date query to give a different amount of rows for each?

1)

```
WHERE
((dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE >= '2019-02-01'
  AND dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE <= '2020-01-31')
OR (dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE >= '2018-02-01'
  AND dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE <= '2019-01-31'))
```

2)

```
WHERE
((dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE >= '2018-02-01'
AND dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE <='2020-01-31'))
```

3)

```
WHERE 
dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE >= '2018-02-01'
AND dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE <= '2020-01-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is selecting 24 months, minus one day (Jan 31st, 2019).

The second query is selecting 24 months.

The third query is equivalent to the second one.

Comment: Thanks! Wait, why is the first one selecting 24 months minus 1 day (2019-01-31)?

Comment: Pressumably `<= '2019-01-31'` gets automatically translated to `<= '2019-01-31 00:00:00'` (beginning of the day). Then the other range starts 24 hours later. You are missing 24 hours right there.

Comment: To add to the comments, it depends on your datatype for the column `dbo.FACTINVOICEHEADER.PAID_DATE`.  If the datatype for this field is `DATE` then it should include all of 2019-01-31 but if the datatype is `DATETIME` the above comment is true.  For your query to work as you expected you should change the datatype to `DATE`